# GuzzleHttp POST Request Data Changed Unexpectedly

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

As per the title, the data that the endpoint receiving is somehow manipulated over the request.

Before submitting the request, I have this array of objects as my data. Notice the length. [image: Array of data before submitting]

So I assume that I will be receiving this data from the endpoint.

And yes, I did. But it is somehow changed. Compare this image to the first one.
[image: Receive data]

What could be done wrong? Here's my guzzle code

```php
$response = $client->request(
    'POST',
    env( 'APP_URL' ) . 'api/migrate',
    [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ],
        'form_params' => [
            'access_token' => $access_token,
            'data' => $data
        ]
    ]
);
```

The $data is the first screenshot.

Comment: Please provide more details. Are both screenshots of the `$data` variable being passed in the form params or what are they? What happens in between each snippet? Do you have any middlewares set up in Guzzle?

Comment: Hey @dbrumann, thanks for the reply. Appreciate it! The first screenshot is the one I'm passing to the form_params which is the $data variable (i'm just showing it as an image so you will see what kind of data I'm passing and the difference of it from the second screenshot)